# firebase analytics hourly granularity reports

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, granularity

I'm trying to display **hourly reports** in the analysis hub of **google analytics for Firebase**. The option is not selectable and I can't get why. There are only two tapable choices among four: daily or weekly reports.

[image: granularity selection for analytics firebase reports]

Since I know it's **doable in the web version of Google analytics** I was wondering if this is the result of a bad configuration of my apps events or if hourly reports are simply not yet available in firebase analytics.

thanks a lot,

Comment: can somebody help me ?